# How do I run same robotframework tests in parallel on multiple platforms?

Tags: testing, automation, robotframework

I'm using Robotframework with RemoteApplications library.
Remote applications library writes out a file to the HOME dir to the user running the test

```
/home/<username>/.robotframework/remoteapplications/launched.txt
```

In my case, the home dir for the user is on a network disk. (The user directory points to the same location irrespective of which machine I access it from)
I'm running the same test on 32 and 64 bit linux platforms and this causes the test to fail because they step on each others toes. Any ideas on how to proceed?